# How to find number of ways to put $n$ different balls in 3 different boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

$n$ is an even number. I have $n$ different balls and I need to put them into $3$ different boxes satisfying conditions:

1. $\frac{n}{2}$ balls are in the first box;
2. Number of balls in the second box is in the form $3k+1$.

It seems simple, but somehow I struggle to see the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you allowed to leave any boxes empty? For example, you have $n=2$ balls and you put one ball into the first box, one ball into the second box, and leave the third box empty. Is that allowed?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, it is allowed

Comment: How many ways you can choose balls for the first box? Then you need to find number of ways to choose balls for the second box which seems to be $1, 4, 7$ etc. Third automatically gets the remaining balls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways to distribute the balls is:
${n\choose n/2}\left({n/2\choose 1}+{n/2\choose 4}+{n/2\choose 7}+\ldots\right)$ (simple combinatorial argument). The trouble is, of course, to calculate the sum in the brackets.

One way of calculating this sum is this: label $\epsilon=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. We know that $\epsilon^3=1$ and $\overline{\epsilon}=\epsilon^2$. Now write the following powers of sums:

$$A=(1+1)^{n/2}=1+{n/2\choose 1}+{n/2\choose 2}+\ldots$$
$$B=(1+\epsilon)^{n/2}=1+{n/2\choose 1}\epsilon+{n/2\choose 2}\epsilon^2+\ldots$$
$$C=(1+\overline{\epsilon})^{n/2}=1+{n/2\choose 1}\overline{\epsilon}+{n/2\choose 2}\overline{\epsilon}^2+\ldots$$

What is $A+\overline{\epsilon}B+\epsilon C$? When you expand this, you will end up with terms of the form $(1+\overline{\epsilon}+\epsilon){n/2\choose 3k}$ (which are all zero as $1+\epsilon+\overline{\epsilon}=0$), with terms of the form $(1+\overline{\epsilon}\epsilon+\epsilon\overline{\epsilon}){n/2\choose 3k+1}$ (the value in the first bracket is actually precisely $3$ as $\epsilon\overline{\epsilon}=1$) ... and with the terms of the form $(1+\overline{\epsilon}^2+\epsilon^2){n/2\choose 3k+2}$ - which are again all zero.

The conclusion is that $A+\overline{\epsilon}B+\epsilon C=3\left({n/2\choose 1}+{n/2\choose 4}+{n/2\choose 7}+\ldots\right)$. Thus, the total number of distributions of the balls is:

$${n\choose n/2}\frac{2^{n/2}+\overline{\epsilon}(1+\epsilon)^{n/2}+\epsilon(1+\overline{\epsilon})^{n/2}}{3}$$

This can be further compactified by noticing that $1+\epsilon=e^\frac{i\pi}{3}, 1+\overline{\epsilon}=e^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}}$, but this would require distinguishing cases for $n/2\pmod 6$. For example, if $n/2\equiv 0\pmod 6$, then $(1+\epsilon)^{n/2}=(1+\overline{\epsilon})^{n/2}=1$, so the formula boils down to:

$${n\choose n/2}\frac{2^{n/2}-1}{3}\text{ when }n\equiv 0\pmod{12}$$

I would leave it to you to finish the calculation for the other five cases.